# pass a linux command line into two executables

Tags: c, linux, redirect

I have a C program which reads its input from the command line, I would like to feed the executable with the output of `ls | wc -m` command, as I need to call two instances of the executable (`./a.out1` , `./a.out2`) using that same input and make them running in parallel (pipes ?).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for: `./a.out $(ls | wc -m)`?

Comment: Yes, actually it works thanks, but I would like to pass that same argument to two executables using a pipe, any suggestions please ?

Comment: Then you need to do more explaining in your question and make it mention more than one executable.

Comment: Then please update your question. We can't help you if you don't ask about it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add those details please and explain whether you want to call two executables with the same input or redirect the input into the first executable and the output of that one into the second or ....

Comment: Call the two executables with the same input

Comment: `OUT=$(ls | wc -m) && ./a1 "$OUT" && ./a2 "$OUT"`? Not sure if that is what you want as you are not bothering to explain clearly.

Comment: Yes for serial execuation that works just fine, but I believe there is a solution using two pipes instead, for parallel execution!

Comment: Why don't you put all your requirements into the question from the start?

Comment: @kaylum does it make sense now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to use a pipe, so first of all you need to adapt your program to read the input from `stdin` instead of `argc` and `argv`. Input passed via a pipe is *not* added to the command line argument list.

To pipe `stdout` of a process to multiple other processes, you can use `tee` and [process substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
ls | wc -m | tee >(./a.out1) >(./a.out2) >/dev/null
```

However, the reason why you require it be piped (as opposed to passed as an argument) isn't clear to me, so storing the output in a variable as suggested in the comments would work just as well for the example you present.